# Block parameters for subroutines

Tags: perl

I've been looking at the [Test::Warn](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Warn) package which takes block parameters. The `warning_like` method has the signature `warning_like BLOCK REGEXP, TEST_NAME`. I would have thought that in this case the brackets are optional as with other subroutines so the following should be equivalent:

```
warning_like {bar()} qr/at Foo.pm line 5/, "Testname";
warning_like({bar()} qr/at Foo.pm line 5/, "Testname");
```

But the second call with the brackets is causing an error:

```
syntax error at t/testfile.t line 34, near "} qr/at Foo.pm line 5/"
Execution of t/testfile.t aborted due to compilation errors.
```

It looks like the block changes the way the function is called. `warning_like` is similar to `map` which [according to the docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) has the following signatures; `map BLOCK LIST` and `map EXPR,LIST`. In this case, brackets make no difference.

```
my @arr = ('a', 'b' ,'c', 'd', 'e');

my @mapped_block_1 = map( {uc($_)} @arr);
my @mapped_block_2 = map( uc, @arr);
my @mapped_expr_1  = map {uc($_)} @arr;
my @mapped_expr_2  = map uc, @arr;
```

What's the difference between these and why do brackets affect the way `warning_like` is called but not `map`? Why isn't a comma needed between the parameters where a block is used as a parameter?

Thanks,

Comment: See also section "prototypes" in [perldoc perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes): *"An & requires an anonymous subroutine, which, if passed as the first argument, does not require the sub keyword or a subsequent comma."*

Comment: Se also [Why is no comma needed between the arguments to map?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19033299/2173773)

Comment: If you put a parenthesis around the arguments the content inside will be evaluated before the prototype parsing, and since the two items inside the parenthesis is not separated by a comma you get a syntax error (since items in a list must be separated by comma)

Comment: Additional info: [The sub prototype is defined `&$;$`](https://metacpan.org/release/Test-Warn/source/Warn.pm#L331). `prototype 'CORE::map'` is undef, [meaning it's special](http://p3rl.org/prototype).

Comment: The `&` prototype can replicate the block form of map, but it is not possible to replicate the `map` function's argument parsing in general without a keyword, source filter or other hackery.

Comment: `warning_like( sub { bar() }, qr/.../, "test")` is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be different because `warning_like ...` is a sub call and `map ...` is an operator invocation.

The are different because the code required to handle the two calling conventions of `map` is reasonable, but handling arbitrary prototypes that include `&` (possibly multiple times) requires compromises.

---

[perlfunc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) leads with the following:

> The functions in this section can serve as terms in an expression. They fall into two major categories: list operators and named unary operators.

`map` is an operator, just like `+`. As an operator, its syntax is independent of that of                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      a sub call.

So that explain why the two syntax can be different, but you also asked why they are different.

For starters, it makes sense for `map` to allow parens because it would provide consistency with the other "functions". So the question is why doesn't `sub name(&)` allow parens for the `name BLOCK` syntax. For that, I'd have to guess, but I believe it's to avoid extremely complex parser code.

Let's start by looking at how a sub with a prototype of `&` can be called.

```
mysub BLOCK       # Parens forbidden.
mysub sub BLOCK   # Parens allowed
mysub \&NAME      # Parens allowed
mysub \&BLOCK     # Parens allowed
mysub \&$NAME     # Parens allowed
mysub \&$BLOCK    # Parens allowed
```

Perl could create parsing rules that match these exactly. But the sub could have a prototype of `&@`, `&$`, `&$$`, `&&`, etc  Having rules that handle all of these is unfeasible. Instead, the parser simply handles the following:

```
mysub BLOCK LIST   # Parens forbidden.
mysub LIST         # Parens allowed
```

If the name of the sub isn't followed by a `{`, the parser first parses the code as if it was a simple list expression, then performs a subsequent check to see if what was produced matches the prototype. You can see that Perl does this from the error message it gives.

Consider the following:

```
$ perl -we'sub mysub(&) { ... } mysub("a'
Can't find string terminator '"' anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

$ perl -we'sub mysub(&) { ... } mysub({});'
Type of arg 1 to main::mysub must be block or sub {} (not anonymous hash ({})) at -e line 1, near "})"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

In the first snippet, Perl is giving an error as if it was parsing a string literal even though a string literal isn't allowed there.

In the second snippet, we can see that `{}` was successfully parsed as an anonymous hash constructor even though that's not allowed there.

---

By the way, this also explains why the `sub` keyword can only be omitted for `&` when it's the first argument.

```
sub mysub2(&&);
sub mysub3($&);

mysub2 BLOCK BLOCK         # Not ok
mysub2 BLOCK sub BLOCK     # ok
mysub2 BLOCK \&...         # ok

mysub3 EXPR, BLOCK         # Not ok
mysub3 EXPR, sub BLOCK     # ok
mysub3 EXPR, \&...         # ok
```

If a prototype of `&...` is always parsed as `BLOCK LIST` (if it starts with `{`) or `LIST` (otherwise), then there's no way to support `BLOCK BLOCK`.